# vim disable automatic decompression

Tags: vim

I want to look at the binary of a compressed file. That is to say, I want to look at the header and stuff like that. Whenever I do `vim myfile.Z` it of course decompresses it (which is usually what I would want). How can I disable this (preferably some sort of command line argument or something so I don't have to edit my .vimrc file back and forth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Vim initialization, you can disable the *gzip plugin* via

```
:autocmd! gzip
```

If you just want to disable the special handling for a single file, I'd use

```
:noautocmd edit myfile.Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the gzip plugin if you add this line to your `.vimrc`

```
:let loaded_gzip = 1
```